# PHP type hint none

Tags: php, loops, iterator

I've build iterator in PHP which has a method that returns an array property when iterator is not valid:

```
class MyIterator... {

    private array $arrayProperty = [];

    public function returnArray():array {

        // Appending values to that array
        // next,current stuff...

        if (! $this->valid()){
            return $this->arrayProperty
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine until I've typehinted return type array.
Now im getting TypeError: Return value must be of type array, none returned.
is there a way how to type hint none?

Comment: as of your declaration this function MUST return an array, but implementation is CAN return array.
As of PHP8 i think you can also do `public function $arr():array|null {}` and retrurn null

Comment: @mech Nullable types were added in PHP 7.1, and are spelled `?array`

Comment: What is the reason for choosing the title? Obviously, the type hint is _not_ "none"!? Also, I found a few matches searching for the error. Lastly, it helps extracting a [mcve] first to further your understanding and also to clearly demonstrate the problem e.g. here.

Answer (score 0):

I will presume the code is this:

```
public function returnArray():array {

    // Appending values to that array
    // next,current stuff...

    if (! $this->valid()){
        return $this->arrayProperty;
    }
}
```

In this case, indeed you are returning nothing. Typehint so and make it explicit:

```
public function returnArray(): ?array {

    // Appending values to that array
    // next,current stuff...

    if (! $this->valid()){
        return $this->arrayProperty;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, any function that doesn't explicitly return a value implicitly returns `null`. Consider the following:

```
function a() {
    // do nothing
}
var_dump( a() ); // null

function b($condition) {
    if ( $condition ) {
       return 42;
    }
}
var_dump( b(true) ); // int(42)
var_dump( b(false) ); // null
```

So your function returns either an array or `null`, which can be declared with a [nullable type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable): `?array`

For clarity, you might want to explicitly write out the `return null`

```
class MyIterator... {

    private array $arrayProperty = [];

    public function returnArray(): ?array {

        // Appending values to that array
        // next,current stuff...

        if (! $this->valid()){
            return $this->arrayProperty;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I feel too strongly about my comment under the question to leave it there and hope that it will be read.

I don't think I have ever made a nullable array return type.  Whatever script is calling the method is expecting iterable data to be returned
not a scalar type.  If there is data, the array is populated.  If there is no data, the array is empty.  If there is something significantly afoul, throw an exception.  I recommend never using `?array` for simplicity of subsequent data processing.

Both `null` and an empty array are "falsey" values.  Returning an empty array is perfectly suitable for falsey checking as well as instantly feeding into a loop or native array function.

I'm considering this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).  Refactor this method to never return `null`.

```
class MyIterator
{
    private array $arrayProperty = [];

    public function accumulateViolations(): array
    {
        $this->valid(); // potentially populates $this->arrayProperty
        return $this->arrayProperty;
    }
}
```